# DataTables age range filter is not working

Tags: html, jquery, datatables, range

I got a problem when filtering the age range in DataTables. I am using `DataTables ver 1.10.10`. I am confused because when I started to build the code it was working properly, but when I tested again, it's not working anymore.

I hope anyone could tell me where I am missing since it is a very noob question.

Here is my javascript

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var from = parseInt( $('#ageFrom').val(), 10 );
        var to = parseInt( $('#ageTo').val(), 10);
        var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0;

        if ( (isNaN(from) && isNaN(to)) || 
             (isNaN(from) && age <= to) ||
             (from <= age && isNaN(to)) ||
             (from <= age && age <= to) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

$('#ageFrom, #ageTo').on('change keyup', function() {
    if ($('#ageFrom').val() == "" || $('#ageTo').val() == "") {
        table.draw()
    }
    else {
        table.draw();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: It seems this `data.[3]` is a typo.

Comment: Yes sorry, Updated now. But still not working

Comment: The `data[3]`, it means the 4th column of data rows are your age column. Does it right?

Comment: Take a look at this page https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search

Comment: Yes since in the first place that code seems working but when I work on another function that is not related to this. It was suddenly not working. `data[3]` return the value of `Year` _(1995)_

Comment: Can you make a runnable snippet?

Comment: Of course it is working, but you have some code that breaks the logic of copy-pase snippet. What that is, we can never know.